# What is the connection between Node and projects that use node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I've used React and React Native for a bunch of projects, and am just starting to learn Node JS separately. I've always used `npm` to download node modules for my projects, and have used commands like `npm start` etc. What I want to know is:

What is the relationship between Node JS itself and frameworks like React that use node modules? Does React use Node JS? If so, in what way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node  is a JS back-end runtime environment (just as the browser is *also* a runtime environment). It's a place where JavaScript can *run*.

React is a front-end framework(web therefore also JS, at least for now). Since they both use the the same language, modules, libraries and packages used in  Node JS and distributed by npm are also most of the time usable on the web (OR VICE VERSA)! And React itself doesn't use  Node JS, back-end could be done in any language. React is pure JS + HTML5. Npm package manager does use Node.

Comment: Hi @Aleks,

Re "packages used in Node JS and distributed by npm are also most of the time usable on the web": Am I understanding correctly that it just happens that the type of modules used by node tend to be useful in React apps, so we take advantage of that by using them in React?


And Re "React itself doesn't use Node" & "Npm package manager does use Node": So am I right that although React can use node modules and we access them with npm, which DOES use Node, React itself doesn't use Node directly?

Comment: yes, also I don't call them node modules. npm or js modules. Npm inc. is private company and they have competitors, like Yarn, albeit it is less popular.

Comment: 'the type of modules used by node tend to be useful in React apps' - not only React apps, web in general.

Comment: This is from wiki, puts it really well - Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment that executes JavaScript code outside of a browser. Node.js lets developers use JavaScript to write command line tools and for server-side scripting—running scripts server-side to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's web browser. Consequently, Node.js represents a "JavaScript everywhere" paradigm,[7] unifying web application development around a single programming language, rather than different languages for server- and client-side scripts.

Comment: I'd be a little careful about calling NodeJS a "language", as it serves the same basic ecological niche as the web browser environment. I didn't change it, but I'd also be a little dubious about saying that most NPM packages are explicitly usable on the web (i.e., front-end). That seems a little bit of an over-generalization, and for someone like OP that's confused about the connection between Node, React, etc., it's a little... dangerous? If that makes any sense.

Comment: @Aleks and Newms , all makes sense, thanks for your insight! Aleks I greened your answer :)